# Set mesh transparency Meshlab

Tags: 3d, transparency, mesh, meshlab

I have a problem using MeshLab. I have three meshes one inside the other and I want to set transparency of the meshes so that I can see the three layers of meshes. Is there any way in Meshlab to set the transparency of a mesh? Thank you very much 
Marco

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it is not possible to set the transparency in Meshlab. I can recommend [GLC_Player](http://www.glc-player.net/) which is capable of displaying transparancies. I use it to work with OBJ files.